# DataTable inconsistencies

Tags: c#

Consider this piece of code:

```
DataRow[] stuff = dt.Select("stuffFiler = " + stuff);
```

Versus

```
DataRow[] stuff = dt.Select("stuffFiler = '" + stuff + "'");
```

The datatable that is the source of the stuff DataRow array ruturns a varchar for the column in question for the filter.  The variable stuff is set to a string, but in some cases the compiler threw an error regarding an int32.

The second version works in all cases now and is a much more clean way to go, but I am curious why the first one worked at all?

Using the 4.5.2 version of the .NetFramework just in case it matters.

**Example data**:
stuff = "123456677" or stuff = "552336677" -- legit varchar / string data

stuffFilter for this example is a varchar column name.

Comment: whats the data type of stuffFiler also

Comment: "but in some cases the compiler threw an error regarding an int32." In what cases? What is the specific error message?

Comment: @ZoharPeled stuff = "123456688" or something similar.  Legit as far as I could see varchar / string data.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 In this example stuffFilter is a column name.

Comment: columns in data tables also have a data type - @MisterPositive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the DataColumn.Expression Property from the Microsoft site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8

Especially this part:

**User-Defined Values**

User-defined values may be used within expressions to be compared with column values. String values should be enclosed within single quotation marks (and each single quotation character in a string value has to be escaped by prepending it with another single quotation character). Date values should be enclosed within pound signs (#) or single quotes (') based on the data provider. Decimals and scientific notation are permissible for numeric values. For example:

"FirstName = 'John'"

"Price <= 50.00"

"Birthdate < #1/31/82#"

For columns that contain enumeration values, cast the value to an integer data type. For example:

"EnumColumn = 5"

---

Basically the apostrophes force the select to handle the variable as string while without them numeric values would be handled as integer or decimal values that cause exceptions with a varchar column.